# Is there an openssl equivalent for SecCertificateAddToKeychain?

Tags: c, security, openssl, certificate, x509

Is there a C API in openssl that is equivalent to `SecCertificateAddToKeychain` of OS X which can be used to store a certificate in a certificate store of choice?

If it is there is it cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

There may be keychain equivalent in other platforms (Windows, Linux or other OS). As far as I know, there is no cross-platform equivalent in OpenSSL related to keychain. However, OpenSSL has its certificate store which is not key chain as it is not used to store passphrases.

As you mentioned, you want `SecCertificateAddToKeychain` equivalent in OpenSSL. In my knowledge, there is no such equivalent.

In Windows, it is protected storage susbsystem.

However, still I would like to suggest to see OpenSSL certificate store i.e. `X509_STORE`. If that suffices your purpose (what you want to do with keychain).

`X509_STORE` is for all the platforms.